# Read table with separator = k white space with k variable

Tags: r, text-files

I have a text file with data separated by white spaces. The number of white space is varying and I cannot use read.table. Do you have advices (ps I am on windows).

Two lines from the file:

```
 13001  200901010200    11.49   -23.01  -999.00
 46001  200904300200    56.30  -148.00  -999.00
```

Comment: `read.table` works with varying white spaces.  Can you post a small sample of the data in your file?

Comment: @Joshua are these two sample lines enough ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even with your edit, the issue still isn't clear.  Your example works for me.

```
Lines <-
"13001  200901010200    11.49   -23.01  -999.00
46001  200904300200    56.30  -148.00  -999.00"

con <- textConnection(Lines)
x <- read.table(con)
close(con)
x
#      V1           V2    V3      V4   V5
# 1 13001 200901010200 11.49  -23.01 -999
# 2 46001 200904300200 56.30 -148.00 -999
```

The default value of `sep=""` works because (as it says in `?read.table`):

> If ‘sep = ""’ (the default for
>   ‘read.table’) the separator is ‘white
>   space’, that is one or more spaces,
>   tabs, newlines or carriage returns.

Comment: oops, I can't believe I did not try without specifying sep parameter... Maybe I should remove my question?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you were doing.  Specifying `sep=" "` means literally one space.  The default of `sep=""` means "whitespace".  See `?read.table` for details.

Answer (score 5):

Using `sep=""` is logically equivalent to any amount of whitespace (in regex terms, `"\s+"`).

To read your data using `read.delim()` or `read.table()`, use:

```
read.delim(fileName, sep="")
```

This also removes leading whitespace (before the first column).